# Adding a profile to a dialogue box

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to create dialogue boxes that contain the profile picture of the speaking character in them. As such, I want the profile pic to be attached to the object itself. If I understand this right, the following creates a variable space for profilePic that I then populate within the GUI.

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NPC : Character {

[SerializeField] private Image profilePic;
}
```

Then over in my dialogue script I have the following:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

//This currently only allows for one sided conversations
//this can be later modified to add profile picture as well as several iterated conversations


public class Dialogue : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private UnityEngine.UI.Text dialogueText;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject dialoguePanel;

    [SerializeField]
    private UnityEngine.UI.Image profilePic;

    private string[] dialogue;
    private int dialogueIndex;


    public void StartDialogue(string[] dialogue)
    {

        dialogueIndex = 0;
        this.dialogue = dialogue;
        dialoguePanel.SetActive(true);
        //This is what actually affects the GUI
        dialogueText.text = dialogue[dialogueIndex];
        this.profilePic = profilePic;


    }
```

The dialogue functions work. It should be taking the contents of this.profilePic and putting them into the UI.image profilePic component, right? The text works. The panel pops up. Just no picture.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Where do you pass the character who is speaking to the Dialogue script?

Comment: Have you tried to pause the game and check the layout? The Unity UI system can be a bit erratic at times. I experienced several times that layout elements ended up with negative size or outside of the visible area.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you have is that you are referencing an `Image` component in your scripts. `Image` is a component of `UnityEngine.UI` which main purpose is to draw `Sprite` in `Canvas`. When you are doing `this.profilePic = profilePic` you are saying that your variable should reference an `Image` component that you have passed to a method. But still you have a logical issue in your code, you don't even reference the component of an NPC, but you are referencing the same component. In a nutshell - `this.image = this.image;`.

`Sprite.Create` - is costly operation and in this instance you can avoid it by directly referencing `Sprite` object.

```cs
public class NPC : MonoBehaviour
{
  [SerializeField] private Sprite npcSprite;
  public Sprite NPCSprite => this.npcSprite;
}

public class Dialogue : MonoBehaviour
{
  [SerializeField] private Image profilePic;

  ...

  public void StartDialogue(..., Sprite profilePic)
  {
    ...

    this.profilePic.sprite = profilePic;
  }
}

// Somewhere in code:
dialogue.StartDialogue(..., npc.NPCSprite);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can re-create the sprite and set the size of the texture 2d being assigned to the pic.

```
                                                             //assign size to match ui pic
this.profilePic.sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, 128, 128), new Vector2(0, 0));
```